# Add persistent collection of objects to another object in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

I am trying to have a collection of `<AppUser>` objects within another `Project` object.

My model:

```
public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please enter a project name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please enter a project description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        //HERE'S MY COLLECTION OF <APPUSER> OBJECTS
        public virtual ICollection<AppUser> ProjectManagers { get; set; }
    }
```

In my view, I ask for an email associated with an `<AppUser>` to add to this list. Here's the ViewModel associated with this view:

```
public class AddProjectManagerViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please ensure email is valid")]
        [UIHint("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    }
```

And the View:

```
@model AddProjectManagerViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add PM";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<div class="col-xs-12 buffer">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h3>Enter the new Project Manager's email:</h3>
    </div>
    <div><span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span></div>

    <form asp-action="AddProjectManager">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Email"></label>
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-projectId="@Model.ProjectID" type="submit">Add to PMs</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

In my controller, I have my POST method. The problem is, the `List<AppUser>` is not persistent and shows up `null` each time the action method is called:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddProjectManager(int projectId, string email)
        {
            var pmToAdd = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            if (pmToAdd != null)
            {
                var proj = repository.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projectId);
                if(proj != null)
                {
                    //HERE proj.ProjectManagers IS ALWAYS NULL EVEN IF THIS METHOD HAS BEEN PREVIOUSLY CALLED SUCCESSFULLY
                    if(proj.ProjectManagers == null) { proj.ProjectManagers = new List<AppUser>(); }
                    proj.ProjectManagers.Add(pmToAdd);
                    TempData["message"] = $"{pmToAdd.Email} added to {proj.Name} Project Managers";
                    return View("Edit", proj );
                }
                TempData["message"] = $"Error finding project in database.";
                return View();
            }
            TempData["message"] = $"User not found. Ensure that email is linked to a registered user";
            return View();

        }
```

How should I set up this approach to make the model's `public virtual ICollection<AppUser> ProjectManagers { get; set; }` persistent?

***EDIT***
Here is my repository method:

```
public void AddProjectManager(int projectID, AppUser user)
        {
            Project proj = context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projectID);
            if(proj != null)
            {
                proj.ProjectManagers.Add(user);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

I've also changed `proj.ProjectManagers.Add(pmToAdd);` to `repository.AddProjectManager(projectId, pmToAdd);` in the action method but `List<AppUser>' is still`null` on each call

Comment: I assume `repository` is an Entity Framework `DbContext`? If so, you are never calling `await repository.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: @DavidG I think I made an edit to address this and, while I think it did point out an error in my method, it didn't fix the issue at hand

Comment: Have you tried to eagerly load the PMs? For example `context.Projects.Include(p => p.ProjectManagers).FirstOrDefault...`

Comment: @DavidG I tried modifying the repository to `public IQueryable<Project> Projects => context.Projects.Include(p => p.ProjectManagers);` but I got the error `"The instance of entity type 'AppUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."`

Comment: @coolhand This is means `AppUser` is already has been loaded into context before loading here. Check your code properly.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I'm sorry but I don't follow. What would be an example of a remedy?

Comment: @TanvirArjel I would suggest VS Live Share extension rather. Allows remote debugging and is limited to the context of visual studio. More likely to have people agree to being helped than having to hand over effectively  full control of your computer :)

Comment: @DavidG I believe your second comment was the key to my issue. After an update on my machine, the collection was persistent (no idea what this had to do with the update). To get ride of the other error, I had to refactor my `proj.UserIsAlreadyPM(user)` function to `proj.UserIsAlreadyPM(user.Id)`. If you'd like credit for this fix, please leave your `Include` statement as the answer.